# How to convert a tcl variable value to specific format

Tags: tcl

how can I convert

```
set var "USE_90a_Sc_ttv"
```

to

```
set out "9.0a ttv Sc"
```

using tcl code?

Regards,
Divesh

Answer (score 0):

Use the [split](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/split.htm), [lassign](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lassign.htm) and [regsub](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm) functions:

```
lassign [split $var _] prefix version type tag
regsub {(\d(\w)?)$} $version {.\1} nversion
set out "$nversion $tag $type"
```

If you are using an older version and don't have lassign available, you
can use [lindex](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lindex.htm) to retrieve specific items from the list returned by split.

```
set tlist [split $var _] 
set version [lindex $tlist 1]
set type [lindex $tlist 2]
set tag [lindex $tlist 3]
regsub {(\d(\w)?)$} $version {.\1} nversion
set out "$nversion $tag $type"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `scan` to parse that, and `list` to assemble the results.

```
set var "USE_90a_Sc_ttv"

# Remember to check the result of [scan] for number of parsed fields
if {[scan $var {USE_%1d%2[^_]_%2[^_]_%3s%c} a b c d e] != 4} {
    error "Unexpected input data! '$var'"
}
set out [list $a.$b $d $c]
```

Putting a `%c` at the end of the format lets me detect if there are any unexpected characters at the end. There shouldn't be; only 4 fields ought to be satisfied. This makes for a quick way to check that what I've got is what I expect. Also, `%2[^_]` is an *unusual* field specifier, but all it does is ask for 2 non-underscore characters.